# Trying to hide password on image click

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

Trying to hide password while clicking on the image, The code are provided below.In the xaml part i have taken textbox for accepting password in the code behind i had written the code for hiding but it is giving error while making visibility false.
Refer image[image]

```
<TextBox Name="txtBoxPassw"  Height="45" Width="246" InputScope="Password" Margin="10,5,5,5" Background="White" VerticalAlignment="Center"  
                         FontSize="25" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" Visibility="Visible" Foreground="Black"  Padding="50,5,5,5" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                         BorderThickness="0,0,0,2" BorderBrush="Gray"  />
                <Canvas Margin="58,-45,136,0">
                    <Image x:Name="passLogo" Source="Assets/ic_pass.png" Height="41" Width="41" />
                </Canvas>
                <!--19oct-->
                <TextBlock Name="txtBlockPasswFieldError" Grid.Row="2" Margin="-60,0,0,0" Foreground="Black" Text="*Please enter valid name"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Visible" FontSize="11"/>
                <!--19oct-->
                <Image Name="showimg" Source="Assets/show_pass.png"  Width="25" Height="50" Margin="50,15,40,10" Tapped="Image_Tapped" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                <TextBlock Name="showPass"
                    Text="Show Password"
                    Foreground="#303030"  
                    FontSize="15"
                    FontFamily="Koblenz Serial Medium" 
                    Margin="200,-45,15,20" />
```

cs file

```
private void Image_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            BitmapImage bitcurrentimage = showimg.Source as BitmapImage;
            //if (showimg.Source == new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/show_pass.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)))
            if (bitcurrentimage.UriSource.AbsoluteUri == "ms-appx:///Assets/show_pass.png")
            {
                //passBox.PasswordRevealMode = PasswordRevealMode.Visible;
                txtBoxPassw.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                showPass.Text = "Hide Password";
                SetImage("ms-appx:///Assets/hide_pass_.png");
            }
            else
            {
                //passBox.PasswordRevealMode = PasswordRevealMode.Hidden;
                txtBoxPassw.Visibility = Visibility.Visible.Equals(false);
                showPass.Text = "Show Password";
                SetImage("ms-appx:///Assets/show_pass.png");
            }

        }
```

Comment: `Visibility.Visible.Equals(false)` doesn't make sense. You certainly want to set `Visibility.Collapsed`.

Comment: no i want the password should hide not collapsed

Comment: [UWP Visibility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.visibility) is either Visible or Collapsed. Or are you able to explain how "hide" is different from Collapsed?

Comment: i mean password  which any one has enter should not visible .means after clicking show password it should visible at same textbox and it should be in (....... )format at same place on clicking hide password

Comment: using Visibility.Collapsed completely hide the textbox

Comment: What's wrong about using a `PasswordBox` and its `PasswordRevealMode` property which you obviously tried (or copied from somewhere else)?

Comment: actually i want to put validation(if (Utility.isEmptyString(txtBoxPassw.Text))  on the string typed in passwordbox, but when i am trying it is giving error "'PasswordBox' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'PasswordBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> actually i want to put validation(if (Utility.isEmptyString(txtBoxPassw.Text)) on the string typed in passwordbox, but when i am trying it is giving error "'PasswordBox' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'PasswordBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

This is your last comment, and from this comment I assume that you accept the method to use the built-in control `PasswordBox` instead of creating your own one.

Then you can refer to [PasswordBox class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.passwordbox.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), unlike a `TextBox` or a `TextBlock`, `PasswordBox` does not have a property named "Text". I think what you need is the [PasswordBox.Password property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.passwordbox.password.aspx).

For example:

```
<PasswordBox x:Name="passwb" Height="30" IsPasswordRevealButtonEnabled="True" />
<Button Content="click" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="Button_Click"  />
```

Code behind:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var pass = passwb.Password;
}
```

The `pass` here indicate the password currently held by the `PasswordBox` which named "passwb".

Answer (score -1):

In Winform there is a textbox parameter 'PasswordChar', if you set it to a character( for example *) it will replace all characters in the textbox to that character. If you set the passwordChar to '\o' (PasswordBox.PasswordChar = '\0';) it will display all the characters like normal. I hope there is something similar in UWP - I am not into UWP.